How long it takes to deploy a contract to bsc test network
I write a simple contract , i can deploy it to ganache , but i need publish it to bnb testnet,
demo.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract demo {
    uint256 public data;

    function set(uint256 _data) public {
        data = _data;
    }

    function add() public {
        data++;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint256) {
        return data;
    }
}


hardhat.config.ts
test: {
  chainId: 97,
  // url:"https://bsc-testnet.public.blastapi.io",
  // url:"https://bsc-testnet.publicnode.com",
  url: "https://bsc-testnet-dataseed.bnbchain.org",
  // url: "https://bsc-testnet.bnbchain.org",
  // url: "https://bsc-testnet-rpc.publicnode.com",
  accounts: ["0x ****"],
  timeout: 10000,
  gasPrice: 100,
},

when i use hardhat :
npx hardhat run ./scripts/deploy.ts --network test

I waited all night, and he kept showing: ,
hardhat:core:hre Creating provider for network test +4s

Can someone tell me some possible reasons
full hardhat.config.ts:
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import '@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades';
import "hardhat-abi-exporter";
import fs from "fs";
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("./private.key", {
  encoding: "utf-8"
});
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.8.17",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        version: "0.6.6",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        version: "0.5.16",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        version: "0.4.18",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200,
          },
        },
      }
    ]
  },
  gasReporter: {
    // enabled  : true,
    currency: 'CNY',
    gasPrice: 5,
  },
  networks: {
    dev: {
      chainId: 97,
      // url:"https://bsc-testnet.public.blastapi.io",
      // url:"https://bsc-testnet.publicnode.com",
      url: "https://bsc-testnet-dataseed.bnbchain.org",
      // url: "https://bsc-testnet.bnbchain.org",
      // url: "https://bsc-testnet-rpc.publicnode.com",
      accounts: ["0xf9b1d***0278e9d4674b2005911e0b2"],
      timeout: 10000
    },
    prod:{
      chainId:56,
      url: 'https://rpc.ankr.com/bsc',
      accounts:[privateKey],
    },
    local:{
      chainId: 1337,
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
      accounts:["0x0f4108bc3a3138acac0fd7****e3e57da929"],
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true
    }
  },
  paths: {
    cache: "./runtime/cache",
    artifacts: "./runtime/artifacts"
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: '****',
  },
  abiExporter: {
    path: './runtime/abi',
    runOnCompile: true,
    clear: true,
    flat: true,
    only: [
      "TPB",
      "TPBGame",
      "TPBMining",
      "TPBWithdraw",
      "demo"
    ]
  }
};

export default config;



--network dev  if the network name is dev in hardhat config,

i am sorry ,I changed my post to make it easier to read, there is no problem here

Can you share your full hardhat.config.ts file?

@SYEDASADKAZMI full config uploaded,thankyou

Instead of the address, you should use the private key in the value of accounts field, like accounts: [privateKey].

@SYEDASADKAZsy There's no problem here, I'm using the private key

Okay. Can you try using the private RPC url that you can get from some provider like Quicknode? Because, I believe Alchemy and Infura don't provide RPC urls for BSC Testnet.

Try to increase the timeout value and check if the endpoint is available.
For nodes of high quality, you can check BSC endpoints by Chainstack. There are the Developer and Growth plans. You can start with the Developer one (free) for your tests.
P.S. I'm a Developer Advocate at Chainstack.

Thank you very much, the answer is so simple, is that the node does not work properly. I switched nodes very quickly.

If you’ve already created the contract you can deploy to (BSC)testnet by using (IDE)remix and METAMASK. The time frame depends on you executing correctly.

I AM REALLY NOT GOOD WITH OPERATING ON BNB CHAIN THIS IS JUST A RECOMMENDATION

OR WELL MAYBE YOU SHOWLD SAY NETWORK.
